# Why the margin on css doesn't work properly for div

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="textAreaWrapper">
<div class="textAreaWrapperPanel">
<h3 class='textblockheader'>Text Block Settings</h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html code, and below is my css code:

```
.textAreaWrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;

}

.textAreaWrapperPanel{

    background-color : #093459;
    color: white;
   margin-top:0px;

}

.textblockheader{
   font-family : "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight : normal;

}
```

I expect there will me no space between `textAreaWrapperPanel` and `textAreaWrapper` div elements, but instead, it still have. But if I change `textblockheader`'s margin-top to `0px`, its work, can anyone explain why this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's cause the browser applies to `H3` elements (and other elements) a margin by default. **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/niqul/1/edit?css,output)**

All you need is to use a *CSS Reset*

To quickly view an ugly rest just use

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;} /* will apply to all (*) elements */
```

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/

---

Regarding your concerns about **[Collapsing Margins][2]**:  
*Why the blue background of the H3's parent DIV does not fully cover the space taken by the `H3` element?*

That's cause you're nesting two `block-level` elements: `h3` into `div`, where the *box models* and *natural floats* are being handled by the browser unless specified like in this three solutions:

- Set `overflow:auto;` to the parent `div`
- Or set your `H3` element as `display: inline-block;`
- Use a *clearfix* for the `block-level` parent element

**[jsBin PLAYGROUND](http://jsbin.com/niqul/3/edit)**

```
/* // uncomment

*{margin:0;padding:0;}

*/

.textAreaWrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.textAreaWrapperPanel{
    /* overflow:auto; */         /* Uncomment this or */
    background-color : #093459;
    color: white;
}

.textblockheader{
   /* display:inline-block; */    /* ... this one or ...*/
   font-family : "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight : normal;
}

/* add this class to your DIV .textAreaWrapperPanel */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content:" "; 
  display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
}
```

Micro clearfix resource: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: but why the blue color of textAreaWrapperPanel seems like applied to h3 only because what I expect is the blue color should cover the "top" part because it doesnt have margin and padding

Comment: @dramasea have you tried using `overflow:auto;` for your `.textAreaWrapperPanel` ?

Comment: that's work, but can i know is there any problem if i didnt put it?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Haha, you even beat me to the block level part, I should just give up now, this is a good answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for your info, do you have a resource or reference so i can refer to?

Comment: @dramasea sorry, but my resource is my experience, I can just advice you to GOog for some terms you don't quite understand and look at the documentation for the use cases.

Comment: @dramasea - The term you are looking for is ["Collapsing Margins"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). It's covered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Alohci thanks so much for the note, I'll add it to the answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that they are already at 0 space between? The two divs both have the same background color and the inner one has no border. Try making the inner one a different color just to see. I bet it will have no upper margin. It's just your H3 tag that by default has a margin.

EDIT:
Sorry I misread your code. You are correct, they are different colors. Here is the WHY of what's going on. Your H3 element is by default presenting as a BLOCK level element. This causes it to have its own background margin that is set to 10px top and bottom. If you were to tell your H3 class textblockheader to:

```
display: inline;
```

It would cause it to remove the background area and margins as well without having to reset anything. As it stands the two divs are touching each other, but the white margin from your textblockheader class is adding extra space that gets the default margin color which is white.

But yeah, the reason it's doing that is the default css styling of H3 elements as block level elements with a default top and bottom margin.

Comment: the inner div have different color actually -> blue, if h3 by default has a margin, why there is still a blank space on top of the inner div?

Comment: @dramasea Looks like you're correct, sorry didn't read your css as closely as I should have. Edited accordingly.

Comment: thanks, is there any reference on the margin touching each other part, so i can know more?

Comment: @dramasea You could try W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp, but really this is from my experience working with HTML so I can't give a specific reference.

Comment: @dramasea this gives a list of all HTML5 block level elements so you know where to look out for this kind of thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: @dramasea this is a pretty good explanation of the concept of block vs inline http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/ and finally collapsing margins reference which is GREAT http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Answer (score 0):

The heading tags have default margins. This link might help:[Default Heading Styles](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.htmlcssdeveloper.com/tutorial/advanced-html-css/what-is-the-default-margin-of-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-h6.html&ei=kUk4U5GHCcWNrQfop4GwCg&usg=AFQjCNFzhVUhl8iWb05qttWwL9fP9fmfCA&sig2=UuFkY2bje9IU-pXyCp7Bsw&bvm=bv.63808443,d.bmk&cad=rja)

Also resetting the default css values of tags may avoid similar future errors: [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)